# Rotate Spark TitleWindow

Tags: flex4, flex-spark

While I was trying to rotate Spark TitleWindow using the following code

```
<s:Rotate id="rotate"  angleBy="360" autoCenterTransform="true" target="{targtObj}"></s:Rotate>
```

it rotates around z-axis. How can I rotate by x-axis or y-axis maintaining the autoCenterTransform="true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a Spark [Rotate3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Rotate3D.html) effect, which enables one to rotate about the other axes.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have an equivalent `angleBy` property, only `angleFrom` and `angleTo` for each of the axes.  If you are rotating 360°, then that isn't that big of a problem, since you would be ending at the starting point:

```
<s:Rotate3D id="rotate3D" target="{targtObj}"
            angleYFrom="0" angleYTo="360"
            autoCenterTransform="true" />
```

Even if you weren't ending at the starting point, getting the same effect as the `angleBy` is still a rather simple matter.  Here is a 30° rotation about the Y-Axis:

```
<fx:Number id="lastAngle">0</fx:Number>
<s:Rotate3D id="rotate3D" target="{targtObj}"
            angleYFrom="{lastAngle}" angleYTo="{lastAngle+30}"
            autoCenterTransform="true" effectEnd="lastAngle+=30"/>
```